# How can I alternate/switch parts of a string in PowerShell without using an intermediate value?

Tags: powershell, replace

I'm trying to alternate a setting in a config file using PowerShell. For example, if a certain value is true, I'd like to switch it to false. If it's false, I'd like to switch it to true. I'd also like to change a path from `\\servername\folder\` to `\\servername\`. Is there a way I can perform this in PowerShell without using an intermediate value?

If I do this:

> `$foo = 'aaa'`
>
> `$foo -replace 'aaa', 'bbb' -replace 'bbb', 'aaa'`

`$foo` will always be `'aaa'`. I realize I could make an intermittent change (`'aaa'` becomes `'ccc'` and then changes to `'bbb'`) but that's messy to read.

How can I alternate values without using an intermediate value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to switch two values without a buffer variable? Or do you want to toggle a value between two states? The latter can be achieved like this:

```
function Toggle($s, $v1, $v2) {
  $e1 = [regex]::Escape($v1)
  $e2 = [regex]::Escape($v2)

  $r = $s
  if ($s -match $e1) {
    $r = $s -replace $e1, $v2
  } elseif ($s -match $e2) {
    $r = $s -replace $e2, $v1
  }

  return ($r)
}

$foo = "..."

Toggle $foo "\\servername\folder\" "\\servername\"
```

Comment: Looks like that might need to be `-replace $e1, $v2` and `-replace $e2, $v1`? Otherwise there's a few extra backslashes.

Comment: Indeed it should. Thanks for the heads up. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Using a match evaluator.  Not sure if this is any better or not.

```
Begin{
[regex]$ValueRegex = 'aaa|bbb'

$ValueToggles = @{
                  aaa='bbb'
                  bbb='aaa'
                 }

$toggleValue = {$ValueToggles[$args[0].groups[0].value]}
}

Process{

$foo = 'Value: aaa'

$ValueRegex.replace($foo,$toggleValue)

}

Value: bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternate a boolean value ($true or $false) simply by using the **-not** operator; e.g.:

```
PS C:\> $value = $true
PS C:\> $value = -not $value
PS C:\> $value
False
```

Regular expression replacement:

```
PS C:\> '\\servername\folder\' -replace '^(\\\\[^\\]+)\\[^\\]+', '$1'
\\servername\
```

Bill

Comment: Ah, I knew that first example would get me in trouble. I'm trying to change a path (`\\servername\folder\ ` would become `\\servername\ `). In any case, I'm using a file and what I'm working with is in fact a string, not a boolean.